# MVC-5 After editing a value, is not displaying the results in other view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, viewbag

Hi I'm new here and English is not my first language, so forgive me for any grammar or spelling mistake.

The problem I'm currently having is when I edit an object and try to display the values in other view.
I've already checked that the object is been save in the database, but when I try to display its value in and other view, it doesn't update.
I have to open and close the app to be updated.

This is the controller code

```
Edit(int? id)
{
    ...
    Teacher teacher = db.Teacher.Find(id);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
Edit(Teacher teacher)
{
    var _teacher = db.Teacher.Find(teacher.id);
    db.Entry(_teacher ).CurrentValues.SetValues(Teacher);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return redirecToAction("DisplayStudent", new {id=Teacher.studentId});
}

DisplayStudent(int? id)
{
    var student = db.Studen.Find(id);
    ViewBag.Teachers = db.Teacher.Where(model => model.studentId ==id).ToList();
    return View(student);
}
```

This the view

```
@model Student

@{
    List<Teacher> Teachers = (List<Model>)ViewBag.Teachers;
}

....

@foreach(var teacher in Teachers)
{
    <p>@teacher.name<p>
    <p>@teacher.lastName<p>
}
```

Comment: Assuming entityframework? or are you using another ORM?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at return View(student); on the DisplayStudent action does your ViewBag.Models contain the expected data? Also, is the casing difference betweeen ViewBag.models in the View compared to ViewBag.Models in the controller just from you copying the code to this? Or is that present in your code as well? ViewBag is indeed case sensitive I am pretty sure.

Comment: yes is entityframework

Comment: The DisplayStudent assigns a value to a var studen, but passes "student"to the view. Where is it getting this student value from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solve the problem, the database wasn't been updated.

All I did was put in DisplayStudent(int? id)

```
DisplayStudent(int? id)
{
    db.dispose();
    db = new dbEntities();
    var student = db.Studen.Find(id);
    ViewBag.Teachers = db.Teacher.Where(model => model.studentId ==id).ToList();
    return View(student);
}
```